# facebook unity access token to firebase

Tags: c#, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, unity-game-engine

so i have my unity app somewhat working. what my problem is now is this:
[the screen which comes up when i press the log in with Facebook button in my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBvLl.png)

is this standard when testing in the unity editor environment?

further, i noticed the screen asks for an access token. what i really want to do is access this token and pass it into the firebase authentication method for Facebook. can I save it as I have in the authCallBack function? if so, do I simply pass the credential created to the accessToken method which invokes the authentication task or am I totally of course? Any help will be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Facebook.Unity;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class FacebookHandler : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
private void Awake()
{
    FB.Init(setInit, onHideUnity);
}

void setInit()
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        Debug.Log("fb is logged in");
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("fb is not logged in");
}

//for whether the game is open or not
void onHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    else
        Time.timeScale = 1;
}

public void fbLogin()
{
    List<string> permissions = new List<string>();

    //asks facebook for the users profile
    permissions.Add("public_profile");
    permissions.Add("email");
    permissions.Add("user_friends");

    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, authCallBack);
}

void authCallBack(IResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(result.Error);

    }
    else
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log("logged in");
            AccessToken token = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            Credential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(token.TokenString);
            accessToken(credential);
        }

        else
            Debug.Log("not logged in");
    }
}

public void accessToken(Credential firebaseResult)
{
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        return;

    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(firebaseResult).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is standard testing screen. you can get test token in your Facebook developer page(Roles->Test User->Click on Edit button-> Get An Access token for this user). Similar token is generated every time your application is connect to your Facebook application. Normally this is a short lived token, around 2 hours so you don't need to save it.

Comment: Okay thanks. If i were to launch my application, is there anything different that i need to do to my code? Ie saving the access token?

Comment: If you plan to develop server side for your application you can debug this token using app access token. Just to be sure that this token is coming from your application but for security, app access token should never be hard-coded into client-side code.

Comment: Hi Boris. still having troubles. I have done the access token debug and when i try to use it on my phone i still get an invalid access token. Is there anything in my code i need to add to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: Did you try to test your login in Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.10